# sort js array by two closest fields

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

i'd like to sort an array by two fields while providing a desired number to sort them by. i tried using lodash but haven't got the desired results.

for example

```
const data = [
  {name: 'first', score: 22, average: 59},
  {name: 'second', score: 34, average: 83},
  {name: 'third', score: 40, average: 24},
  {name: 'fourth', score: 29, average: 49},
  {name: 'fifth', score: 23, average: 55}
];
// call function like this
sortByTwoFields({field:'score', number:21}, {field:'average', number:50});
```

the desired result would be

```
const result = [
  {name: 'fifth', score: 23, average: 55},
  {name: 'fourth', score: 29, average: 49},
  {name: 'first', score: 22, average: 59},
  {name: 'third', score: 40, average: 24},
  {name: 'second', score: 34, average: 83}
];
```

any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: why you are sending *number*?

Comment: What do you mean by "*sort them by a number*"? What would your expected result look like?

Comment: i want to sort them by the closest results to the number im sending

Comment: Please give the exact array you would expect as a result of running this function. Are you prioritising the first field?

Comment: i've updated the question with the desired result

Comment: im trying not to prioritize any field, but instead to have the best/closest result of the two fields to appear on top desc

Comment: You provided incorrect expected result. The item with the name `fourth` should go before the item with the name `first` because item with the name `fourth` has distance equal to 9 and the item with the name `first` has distance equal to 10.

Comment: exactly, the expected result is incorrect. how come score 40 is score 34?

Comment: you are right about the expected result, it's now fixed in my question. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

How about simply use `_.sortBy` of `lodash`??

`_.sortBy(data, [a=> Math.abs(a.score - 21), a=> Math.abs(a.average - 50)])`

Isn't this enough?

**EDIT**

Well, Yes! if you need this sorting (execution) from one place and with only (exactly that 2) 2 nested fields, then this ole liner is ok, but if you are calling from several places and with diff fields (nested) with closest value, then you can wrap this in a function, prepare the itarees dynamically and pass it to `sortBy`.

Here is a working example for that:

```js
var data = [
  {name: 'first', score: 22, average: 59},
  {name: 'second', score: 34, average: 83},
  {name: 'second', score: 34, average: 80},
  {name: 'third', score: 40, average: 24},
  {name: 'fourth', score: 29, average: 49},
  {name: 'fifth', score: 23, average: 55}
];

function sortByClosest(arr, ...fields) {
    //this will create array of callbacks, similar to what user in first example
    let iteratees = fields.map(f => o => Math.abs(f.number - o[f.field]));
    return _.sortBy(arr, iteratees);
}

//pass data for "arr" argument, and all other
//sort key/closest-value for fields array argument
var res = sortByClosest(data, {field:'score', number:21},{field:'average',number:50});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

However key, closest value can be passes in more shorter format like
`{score: 21, average: 50}`, in that case the logic to generate iteratees
needs to adjust accordingly, so it will became:

`_.map(fields, (v,k)=> o=> Math.abs(v - o[k]))`

And you need to call it with a single object (as shown above), here is the call for that:

`sortByClosest(data, {score: 21, average: 50});`

Comment: Thanks this is actually the simplest solution!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your desired result is slightly off as `fourth` has a total difference of 9 while `first` has a total difference of 10. The function below is called like `sortByTwoFields(data, {field:'score', number:21}, {field:'average', number:50})`. You can add a `weight` attribute to an object if you want to prioritize it, otherwise it defaults to 1.

```
function sortByTwoFields (data, info1, info2) {
    if (! ("weight" in info1)) {
        info1.weight = 1;
    }
    if (! ("weight" in info2)) {
        info2.weight = 1;
    }
    return data.sort(function (a, b) {
        var adiff1 = a[info1.field] - info1.number;
        var adiff2 = a[info2.field] - info2.number;
        var bdiff1 = b[info1.field] - info1.number;
        var bdiff2 = b[info2.field] - info2.number;
        return Math.abs(adiff1) * info1.weight + Math.abs(adiff2) * info2.weight - Math.abs(bdiff1) * info1.weight - Math.abs(bdiff2) * info2.weight;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your expected result is correct as the fourth has a smaller total difference.

Anyway, the function will work out the total difference between the values and the numbers given and then sort by that total.

```js
function sortByTwoFields(data, field1, field2) {
  data.sort(function (a, b) {
    // Work out difference of two fields and add them together to get the total
    var totalDifferenceA = Math.abs(field1.number - a[field1.field]) + Math.abs(field2.number - a[field2.field]);
    var totalDifferenceB = Math.abs(field1.number - b[field1.field]) + Math.abs(field2.number - b[field2.field]);
    
    // If a has a smaller total then b it should come first
    return totalDifferenceA - totalDifferenceB;
  });
}

const data = [
  {name: 'first', score: 22, average: 59},
  {name: 'second', score: 34, average: 83},
  {name: 'third', score: 40, average: 24},
  {name: 'fourth', score: 29, average: 49},
  {name: 'fifth', score: 23, average: 55}
];

sortByTwoFields(data, {field: 'score', number: 21}, {field: 'average', number: 50});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as easily make it generic by sorting by any number of fields, not just two:

```
function sortByFields(objs, fields) {
  const diffToFields = obj =>
    _(fields).map(f => Math.abs(obj[f] - f.number)).sum();
  return _(objs).sortBy(diffToFields).value();
}

const sortedData = sortByFields(data, [
  {field: 'score', number: 21},
  {field: 'average', number: 50},
]);
```

Comment: can you provide a use case?